# Add taxonomy terms to search autocomplete

Tags: 8, search

I have a Drupal 8 website with default search bar in my homepage. I have installed the [Search Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) extension to extend its functionality. Everything works great, except it does not suggest taxonomy terms. Can you give me an idea to add taxonomy terms to its suggestions?

**Update:**

I'm sorry that this is not the question I suppose to ask, as I have mistaken the issue. The default search block, does not search taxonomies, but search for the content which belongs to that taxonomy. Let me show you an example:

[image: Example]

Here the ***Vancouver*** is a taxonomy term, and the things that listed(ZHR DEL, Gas Town, etc.) are content which belongs to this term. If you type the same thing in autocomplete, it does not suggest above content nor taxonomy term.

What I want is to suggest the taxonomy in autocomplete, and show the taxonomy term in the search result. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Is it searching for taxonomy terms as well and the same time not autocompleting them, or it is not searching for them at all? 
It's not clear.

Comment: @ssibal Sorry. My mistake. It does not search taxonomy terms at all.

Answer (score 1):

Default search can either display users or content. Apart from this it won't show you any results.